# Use JQ Select to format a JSON data

Tags: json, jq

Use JQ Select to format a JSON data
JSON Data

```json
{
    "header": [
        "key1: value1",
        "key2: value2",
        "key3: value3"
    ]
}
```

Need to convert the header array into object:

```json
{
    "header": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2",
        "key3": "value3"
    }
}
```

I have tried using

```
{header: [.header[]]}
```

But this converts into an array

```json
{
    "header": [
        "key1: value1",
        "key2: value2",
        "key3: value3"
    ]
}
```

Comment: You can't have an object with multiple of the same keys.

Comment: Also your second code bock isn't valid JSON. please fix.

Comment: Added edits to post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.header |= (map(split(": ") | { (.[0]): .[1] }) | add)
```

Will produce:

```json
{
  "header": {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3"
  }
}
```

#### [Try it online](https://jqplay.org/s/RRmgc8B7dfa)

---

- Update the `header` key `.header |=`
- [`map()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#map(x),map_values(x)) over the array items
- [`split()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#split(str)) on `:`  to get the `key` and `value`
- Create an object with first index as key, second as value `{ (.[0]): .[1] }`
- [`add`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#add) them together to create a single object